# Application Signature for 2 days in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I wanted add application signature for some application, which will be valid only for 1 or 2 days. I did enough googling but did not find enough info. So Please let me know how can i make a application get expired in 2 days..

Answer (score 1):

simply add an alarm of calculating time equals to 2 days at the very first start of the app.
When the alarm gets expired you will get the callback and set a global flag as false.
Code in your app that if that flag is false, display a lock screen

Comment: But cleaning the data will remove the Shared preference data... so it may not work for a well known android user

Comment: If you want such a security then you must add a server interaction in your app so that app will make a simple call to notify and check the status of the app.

Comment: Also if making a server is smthing hard, you can use google docs forms to achieve this. Send the IMEI to identify and flag as the value. Then at the app start fetch the same value for app.

Comment: Or the simplest way would be to create a file on the sd card and save the status in it.

Comment: thnx but dont forget to accept my ans if you were satisfied by it. else if you find a different approch then post it in your ques so that we also come to know.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the first start time in `SharedPreferences` and then on each start compare the current time with the saved one. If the 2 days have passed, you can do what ever action you want.

It will probably not be possible to automatically remove the app from the device though.

Answer (score 0):

If your app sends data to a server, you should store the "first run time" there. Storing it locally on the phone (for example `SharedPreferences`) is not very safe as it's easily overcome by changing the phone's time settings.